# Динамическое обновление HTML страничек

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, tomcat

Есть простое Java Web приложение. Один websocket и index.html. Если запустить это на Tomcat  и внести изменения на html страничке (допусти добавить div), то для того чтобы увидеть изменения приходится делать рестарт сервера, что занимает не мало времени. Есть ли решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А Вы где правите html? Если в самом tomcat после развертывания приложения, то рестарт не нужно делать. Если же правки делаете где-то у себя, то редеплой приложения нужен. Рестарт не нужен ни там, ни там.

UPD: Настройте авторазвертывание проекта [тыц](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com.by/2013/10/hot-deployment-with-intellij-idea.html)

Comment: Я правлю его в Intellij Idea, Tomcat тоже запускаю через него

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все отлично!